# jQuery UI autocomplete suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have simple jQuery UI autocomplete, which was working and now it's not. The code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    var cities = new Array();
                    cities.push({"label" : "Chicago", "value" : 1});
                    cities.push({"label" : "Houston", "value" : 2});
                    response(cities);
                },
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log(ui.item.label);
                    $(this).text(ui.item.label);
                    //console.log($(this).text());
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //console.log($(this).text());
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    //console.log($(this).text());
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //console.log($(this).text());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input id="city" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using the focus handler to show the label in the textbox instead of the value (which is what the autocomplete does by default). What is happening now is that the textbox is showing neither label nor value, it is showing the value that I have typed (say 'Chi')

This was working but now it's not. I thought it was because I had included some other javascript and there was a function name clash. But I moved it to a separate HTML as you can see above and it's still not working.

BTW if I uncomment those console log statements and from the dropdown I select Chicago, then all of them print Chicago.

This seems like some silly mistake somewhere but has me stumped. Any suggestions?

EDIT 1: BTW, if I remove the focus and select handlers then the autocomplete works with its default functionality.

EDIT 2: Would be great if someone can test this on their own computer

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle that works for me (jQuery 1.8.0, jQuery UI 1.8.23): http://jsfiddle.net/NkBfm/. The only thing to change is `.text` to `.val`, but you say it works in certain cases so that might not be it.

Comment: I have created [fifdle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnrtP/) hover problem is solved but can't find why select is not giving the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes from default functionality which you appear to be attempting here.

1. You would like the "completed" variable to be previewed in the main input when it is selected
2. You would like the label, not the value, to be shown when a selection has been made.

The reasons that neither of these are currently working are related and simple: `<input>` fields only have a value associated with them, not a separate "label" and "value". When you select an "autocomplete" option from the list, it is the "value", which gets filled in.

For point 1, the part which is being updated by the `focus:` event, just replace `.text(...)` with `.val(...)`, as that is the attribute of the `<input>` field which you actually want to update:

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    event.preventDefault();
},
```

For point 2, as you actually want the field to be filled in by the label, not the value, you could just fill in the same text for both (the default if a flat array is given):

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    var cities = new Array();
    cities.push("Chicago");
    cities.push("Houston");
    response(cities);
},
```

Remember that autocomplete is always *optional*. All you need to fill in for the `value:` is something which you back-end can fully disambiguate. That could be an `id`, but it usually makes sense to use something which the user might have typed in on their own. Of course, if you're doing that, it may also make sense to use `ui.item.value` instead of `ui.item.label` in the `focus:` event, as well.

With the source made sane as above, you can drop the `select:` event entirely.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading question. I had converted the text() to val() and it worked and then I forgot to check it in :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the assignment of the autocomplete source. This works for me:

```
$(function() {

    var cities = [ 
        {"label": "Chicago", "value": 1}, 
        {"label": "Houston", "value": 2}
    ];                    


    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: cities, // assign the source directly
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log(ui.item.label);
            $(this).text(ui.item.label);
            //console.log($(this).text());
            event.preventDefault();
            //console.log($(this).text());
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //console.log($(this).text());
            event.preventDefault();
            //console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
});​
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jN2Wm/1/)

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. But thanks for taking the time